# How to force submit a form after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to build a form with time constraints. The form would display remaining time, and would auto-submit it after 2 minutes.

I wrote this in the HTML:

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST" id="form_id">
```

And this in javascript:

```
if(time < 0)
{
    document.forms["form_id"].submit();// Form submission
}
```

However, I'm not getting the desired results.
I think this may be due to my php form validation. I've used the condition:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Where 'submit' is the name of a button element. I think this button doesn't get set and that prohibits the after-steps to be performed.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your button an id `submit-btn` as:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

And in JavaScript put this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('submit-btn').click();
}, 120000);
```

Comment: This did work! I think that what I did earlier also submitted the form, but my php script ended the validation. This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this form submit after 2 minutes.

```html
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('#form_id').submit();
}, 120000);
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery js file? It depend on jQuery.js file. Please check error in your browser console. If you have some errors then fix that, it will work.

Comment: Yes I've included the jQuery lib. I know the reason due to which it doesn't work. I've wrote the if condition in my php script which checks the submit value. When js forces the form submission, that parameter isn't set. Therefore no further action takes place...

Comment: So there wasn't a submit button in your form?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using button i.e. `<button name="submit">Submit</button>`
try to change it with this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

OR do following

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit"/>
<button >Submit</button>
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("submit").click();
}, 10000);
</script>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST" id="form_id">
<!-- Your fileds -->

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
  echo "sumbit";
}

?>
```

Comment: Will clicking the button alter the hidden field's value?

Comment: why you have to alter value?  `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` become true for hidden field also